# How can I resolve Windows 7 BSOD after wake up from sleep?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sleep

All drivers are up to date. When I wake it up from sleep, Windows 7 respond slow just like virus infect. Then I get BSOD and system restart. I don't have virus infect. BlueScreenView says BSOD cause by driver `ntoskrnl.exe`. Bug Check String: `CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What drivers were loaded at the time?

Comment: Try starting in safe mode to isolate the problem.

Comment: What is the bug check code ? 0x0000007a (0x..14) ?

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: I don't know what drivers were loaded at the time,safe mode doesn't have sleep option right?bug check code is 0x000000f4.Here is the dmp file https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv583w222p11zdt/022415-11622-01.dmp?dl=0

Comment: I change Windows7 HDD SATA port to 1,and problem solved.However I still don't know why this happened.

Comment: post this as an answer. the dmp was not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought Onda H61C V8 MOBO,this MOBO can not sleep.